# Match only the first occurrence of a phrase

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I have the following Json:

```
{"field1": "someText",
  "field2": "Text Again",
  "field3": "Text Again"}
```

I would need to match the first occurrence of any phrase starting with a capital letter (such as "Text Again", for example)

I have written the following:

```
("[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+")
```

It does work fine when testing with https://regex101.com/, for instance. However, it does not seem to correctly function as part of the usage of [ReplaceTextWithMapping](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceTextWithMapping/index.html) (Apache NiFi). Is the regex incorrect?

Thank you for your help

Comment: the regex is fine.

Comment: try `[A-Z][A-Za-z]*\s[A-Z][A-Za-z]*`

Comment: @sweaver2112, actually no, the regex does not do what innuendo is looking for. The construct `[A-Za-z]` will match any upper or lower case, where as innuendo is looking to constrain this to just phrases starting with a capital letter.

Comment: @rock321987, yes [A-Z][A-Za-z]*\s[A-Z][A-Za-z]* does work, but apparently the issue is with the space in the phrase sentence and how it is dealt with from within the Apache NiFi processor. By substituting \s with an underscore and modifying the regex to "[A-Z][a-z]*_[A-Z][a-z]*", the replacement now occurs. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted my findings on the issue to the Apache NiFi mailing list:

http://apache-nifi-developer-list.39713.n7.nabble.com/Issues-with-Regex-used-with-ReplaceTextWithMapping-where-am-I-going-wrong-tc10592.html

I have not received any confirmation from the community, but it seems to me that, although the regex `[A-Z][A-Za-z]*\s[A-Z][A-Za-z]*` is correct in this case, the processor (ReplaceTextWithMapping) does not deal well with blank spaces (\s) and the string contains space between two words.

Answer (score 2):

## Description

```
:\s*"\s*(?=[A-Z])(?![^"]*?\s[a-z])([A-Za-z\s]+)"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression does the following:

- finds the first title case string in value side of what appears to be JSON encoded string
- ensures each word is capitalized
- returns the value inside the quotes as capture group 1

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/eO0xW6/1

**Source String**

```
{"field1": "someText",
  "field2": "Text again",
  "field3": "Text Again"}
```

**First Match**

```
Text Again
```

## Explanation

**Summary**

- `:\s*"` validates that where only checking the value side of the JSON
- `\s*` matches any spaces after the opening quote if they exist
- `(?=[A-Z])` ensure the first character in the string is uppercase
- `(?![^"]*?\s[a-z])` looks for any spaces that are followed by a lower case character. If found then this isn't a match
- `([A-Za-z\s]+)` captures all the characters inside the quote
- `"` matches the quote

**Detailed**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*?                   any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Za-z\s]+              any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to
                             'z', whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and "
                             ") (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have tested and it actually works with "\s*(?=[A-Z])(?![^"]*?\s[a-z])([A-Za-z\s]+)" : https://regex101.com/r/uM0rQ6/1

Unfortunately, it appears that the Apache NiFi ReplaceTextWithMapping does not deal well with space. See my post here: http://apache-nifi-developer-list.39713.n7.nabble.com/Issues-with-Regex-used-with-ReplaceTextWithMapping-where-am-I-going-wrong-tt10592.html#a10598

Comment: then you should post that as the answer to your own question, then mark your answer as the accepted answer.